# TypeError: SetStrength() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strength'

Tags: python, oop

I am struggling to make this simple code work.  I've just started to learn OOP. I looked at other examples but none could point in the right direction. The error is
TypeError: SetStrength() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strength'

```
import random

class Character:
    """A game character that has strength and skill"""

    #constructor
    def __init__(self):

        #set the attributes with an initial value

        self._name = ''
        self._strength = 0
        self._skill = 0

    def SetName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def SetStrength(self, strength):
        self._strength = calculateAttribute()

    def SetSkill(self, skill):
        self._skill = calculateAttribute()

    def GetName(self):
        return self._name

    def GetStrength(self):
        return self._strength

    def GetSkill(self):
        return self._skill

    def report(self):

        return{'name':self._name,'strength': self._strength, 'skill':self._skill}

def calculateAttribute():

    return (random.randrange(1,13)//random.randrange(1, 5)) + 10
    
        
            
def main():
    player1 = Character()
    player1.SetName('James')
    player1.SetStrength()
    player1.SetSkill()
    print(player1.report())
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `player1.SetStrength()` needs `strength` passing to it.

Comment: I thought the SetStrength method would call calculateAttribute function to generate a random number, that was my intention.  I would like to call calculateAttribute( ) function to set the strength.  How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks Noxy.  That worked perfectly and cleared my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

That method is defined as `def SetStrength(self, strength):`. That means that, in addition to the `self` which is passed automatically, you need to provide an additional argument - in this case, the new strength value you'd like to set. It works very similarly to `setName`, which you call with an argument on the previous line.

That said, the code you're working with is Java/C++/etc. code translated into Python, which balloons the size of the code for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the expected argument "strength" of your function "SetStrength". Same for "skill" and "SetSkill".

Try this:

```
def SetStrength(self):
    self._strength = calculateAttribute()

def SetSkill(self):
    self._skill = calculateAttribute()
```